# Приставки "недо" и "до" и частица "не"

Tags: орфография

*Неумело приготовлен обед: что-то недожарилось, что-то недоварилось.*

В этих глаголах приставка "недо"?

Answer (score 1):

*Неумело приготовлен обед: что-то недожарилось, что-то недоварилось*.

Да, здесь **приставка недо- со значением недостаточности, неполноты действия:   пожарилось, сварилось, но не до нормы,** плохо, недостаточно. Об этом значении говорит наречие **неумело**.

Можно себя проверить: недо- заменить на пере-. Недожарилось-пережарилось, недоварилось-переварилось.

Значение незавершённости действия было бы в таком примере: Он не дожарил котлеты, не доварил суп, схватил сумку и убежал.(А потом дожарит и доварит). Вот здесь точно не довёл действие до конца, важна незавершённость действия, а не качество.

У Высоцкого:

А он шутил – недошутил,

Недораспробовал вино

И даже недопригубил.(всё плохо сделал)

Он начал робко с ноты «до»,

Но не допел её, не до...

Не дозвучал его аккорд (не довёл до конца.)

(В. Высоцкий «Прерванный полет»).

Answer (score 0):

В общем, разница в том, что, когда есть приставка "недо-", "не" отделить нельзя. А когда приставка "до-" можно.

> НЕДО- — сложная приставка, указывающая на неполноту, недостаточность действия или качества, например, недолить, недовыпуск, недоразвитый. Она состоит из двух самостоятельно употребляемых элементов: приставки «до-», обозначающей достижение цели, доведение действия до конца (доесть, доехать, дочитать, дожить), и частицы «не-», которая отрицает то, что «до» обозначает (недоесть, недоехать...). Первичным значением приставки до-, которая генетически восходит к предлогу *до,* было значение пространственно-временного предела (долететь, добрести, дожить, дождаться). Семантика данных приставочных образований препятствовала слиянию глагольной основы с отрицательной частицей *не.* Именно для этой группы глаголов в современном русском языке характерно всегда раздельное написание с отрицательной частицей
>   (не долететь, не добрести, не дожить, не дождаться). В возвратных глаголах с приставкой до- (конструкция до- + -ся.) не бывает приставки недо-: не добудиться, не дозвониться, не достучаться, не додуматься... Структурные особенности основы глаголов (добы/ть, доказ/а/ть, довер/я/ть, доним/а/ть...), в которых *до* не является приставкой, препятствуют слиянию с отрицательной частицей *не,* а следовательно, и образованию сложной приставки недо-. Поэтому: не добыть, не доказать, не доверять, не донимать... Неполнота действия, проявляющаяся в отсутствии достаточной нормы, связана в глаголах:
>   1) с недостатком количества чего-либо (недобрать, недовесить недодать, недолить),
>   2) с недостатком протяженности чего-либо во времени (недодержать, недопеть, недоспать, недокиснуть),
>   3) с недостаточной степенью интенсивности действия (недоглядеть, недосмотреть, недослышать, недовидеть).
>   Наиболее многочисленной является первая группа глаголов. Среди глаголов с НЕДО- есть те, которые без НЕ не употребляются (недомогать, недопонять, недоиспользовать, недооценить недолюбливать, недослышать, недоумевать, недосчитаться...) Глаголы *домогать, допонять, доиспользовать, дооценить, долюбливать, дослышать, доумевать, досчитаться* отсутствуют в языке. Глаголы с приставкой до- в значении "дополнительно совершить действие, довести до необходимой нормы": *недоплатить – заплатить неполностью* и *не доплатить – не произвести дополнительной оплаты за переработку.* Один глагол с пространственным значением: не довезти (не доставить до какого-либо места, не довезти до дома) и недовезти (привезти что-либо в меньшем количестве, чем положено, недовезти хлеба). Глаголы с приставкой до- в значении
>   довести действие до конца недоговорить – умолчать о чём-то и не договорить – замолчать, не досказав; недосмотреть за ребёнком (допустить упущение при надзоре) и не досмотреть спектакль до конца (не окончить смотреть); безработные постоянно недоедали; дети часто не доедали за обедом свой суп.

[Источник (после стишков).](https://grammatika-rus.ru/glavnaya/morfemnyj-razbor/morfemika-v-pesnyah/nedo-i-ne-do/)

Comment: Выложите источник, пожалуйста.